# Trying to add a class if another already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

This is a multi layered issue, not sure if it'll fly if I ask it all, but the issue I'm having is Lightbox related.

I am trying to get it working, when I click on an image, the img lightboxes open, but even with `'disableScrolling': true,` it doesn't work. `body` does get `overflow: hidden;` from that lightbox option, but the page still scrolls.

So, I've got to figure out a hacky fix. I tried this js but it's not working:

```
$( ".smile-thumb-container" ).click(function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('lb-disable-scrolling')) {
        $('html').addClass('lb-overflow-fix');
    } else {
        $('html').removeClass('lb-overflow-fix');
    }
});
```

I'm basically trying to say when I click on an `img`, body gets `.lb-disable-scrolling`. This is from Lightbox itself, now, I want to say when I click on the `div` that holds the `img` to check if `<body>` has `.lb-disable-scrolling`, which it'll have because lightbox does this. If body has that class, add a class to `<html>` called `.lb-overflow-fix`. When I close the img, `<body>` loses `.lb-disable-scrolling` so `html` should remove `.lb-overflow-fix` too.

`.lb-overflow-fix` in my css is `overflow: hidden;` I'm not sure why it works on `<html>` and not `<body>`.

I know actual sites aren't ideal, but I can't even get it working in a fiddle properly, so I have to assume my js is incorrect. This is the [site](https://www.ankitdesigns.com/demo/bysc/smile-moments/) the issue is on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you set this CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This changes how vertical scrolling is handled by default, and the result is that it's your `<html>` node that handles it, rather than the `<body>` node.

Remove that `overflow-x: hidden;` from the `<html>`, and suddenly your site works as intended.

It is a bad idea to hide horizontal overflow anyway, so I'd recommend not trying to.